# EAR is not getting deployed on jBoss server in maven

Tags: maven, deployment, jboss, jboss7.x, maven-3

I am trying to deploy my EAR on jBoss server using maven. This is my pom entry

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.1.Final</version>

            <executions>

             <execution>
                    <id>jboss-undeploy</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>undeploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>clean</phase>
             </execution>

             <execution>
                    <id>jboss-deploy</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                  </execution>
            </executions>

             <configuration>
                <force>true</force>
                <jbossHome>${jboss.directory}</jbossHome>
                <serverName>dummyserver-standard</serverName>

                <hostName>localhost</hostName>
               <username>ashutosh</username>
              <password>password</password>
                <port>7001</port>
                <fileNames>
                    <fileName>/target/RightsEar-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear</fileName>
                </fileNames>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I run the command "clean install -U -X" because I have configured my pom to deploy the EAR in install phase. I am below error

```
java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could not connect to remote://localhost:7001.    
The connection timed out
```

I have tried many solutions given in  stackoverflow but nothing helped. Kindly suggest me the solution..any help is appreciated

Comment: are you using correct port number?

Comment: yes.. I am...i have configured it on 7001 port number

Comment: I am talking about management port in standalone.xml not about 8080/8443. By default it is 9999. Can you double check it and share your standalone.xml if not working.

Comment: What OS are you running? Check the logs of the JBoss AS 7 server running. If you're on Linux or OS X generally you're not allowed to bind to ports below 8000 without being root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of hit and trial finally I got my EAR deployed but it ran only 2 times after that it is showing me the error that EAR structure is not proper.
I googled it and found that it is a bug in jBoss 7.1.1.

[link](https://henk53.wordpress.com/2013/01/09/the-curious-case-of-jboss-as-7-1-2-and-7-1-3/)